# Finding the next occurrence of particular day of the week

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, dayofweek

How can I take a datetime column `start_at` convert it to a day of week and find out the next future occurrence relative to the current date?

Here I'm trying to add the DOW to the current week but it doesn't appear to be correct.

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', current_date) + CAST(extract(dow from start_at) || ' days' AS interval)
```

Full example:

```
SELECT id event_id,
GENERATE_SERIES(date_trunc('week', current_date) + CAST(extract(dow from start_at) + 1 || ' days' AS interval) + start_at::time, current_date + interval '3 weeks', '1 week'::INTERVAL) AS start_at
FROM events
```

## Events

```
+-----+---------------------------+---------------------+
| id  | start_at                  | recurring_schedule  |
+-----+---------------------------+---------------------+
| 358 | 2015-01-23 20:00:00 +0000 | Weekly              |
| 359 | 2016-01-22 19:30:00 +1100 | Monthly             |
| 360 | 2016-02-01 19:00:00 +1100 | Weekly              |
| 361 | 2016-02-01 20:00:00 +0000 | Weekly              |
| 362 | 2014-02-13 20:00:00 +0000 | Bi-Weekly           |
+-----+---------------------------+---------------------+
```

## Output

```
+----------+---------------------------+
| event_id | start_at                  |
+----------+---------------------------+
| 35       | 2018-04-11 19:30:00 +0000 |
| 94       | 2018-04-12 20:00:00 +0100 |
| 269      | 2018-04-13 18:30:00 +0100 |
| 45       | 2018-04-13 20:00:00 +0100 |
| 242      | 2018-04-13 19:30:00 +1100 |    
| 35       | 2018-04-18 19:30:00 +0000 |
| 94       | 2018-04-19 20:00:00 +0100 |
| 269      | 2018-04-20 18:30:00 +0100 |
| 45       | 2018-04-20 20:00:00 +0100 |
| 242      | 2018-04-20 19:30:00 +1100 |
+----------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: What results did you observe? What results did you expect to see?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired output and a sample dataset?

Comment: If I got your question right, perhaps something like this? `SELECT * FROM t
WHERE 
  EXTRACT(DOW FROM start_at)>=EXTRACT(DOW FROM CURRENT_DATE);`

Comment: @JimJones Updated my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT id event_id,    
GENERATE_SERIES(date_trunc('week', current_date)::date 
+ (extract(isodow from start_at)::int - 1) + start_at::time, current_date 
+ interval '3 weeks', '1 week'::INTERVAL) AS start_at
FROM events
```